# How to use ceasar cipher with dictionaries?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

How would I cipher the following dictionary?:

```
('', '', 'newpwd', 'gdfhjhgdfhgdf', '11A7AC66816E87CF0AE7AE1891DA159095A1049A96B3A8546C8A51B381F568D8705811BBDD2B89385ACE8DF1B12C2B8CA17524E4C7F79354D8C4025316FCD13C0CDD87C455B99B0AB647DD5A134BF675AE0EA08D3D997518FF065510FC497F780B43D05F', 'e=10001;m=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')
```

I was doing this but I got an error:

```
def encrypt(text, s):
    result = ""
    # transverse the plain text
    for i in range(len(text)):
      char = text[i]
      # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text
  
      if (char.isupper()):
         result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
      # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
      else:
         result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
      return result
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\main\main.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\main\main.py", line 105, in genaccount
    "CipherValue": encrypt(cipher, 1),
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\main\main.py", line 25, in encrypt
    result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

How do I make the encrypting this dictionary a function so I can just do encrypt(dictionary)

line 105 is where I'm trying to encrypt the dictionary:
"CipherValue": encrypt(cipher, 1),

Comment: I think it is because of empty values in your tuple. Remove them and you will be fine

Comment: nope its not, i removed and still doesn't do anything

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What is `cipher` in your program?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It's the dictionary in the question

Comment: Your full error traceback shows that `encrypt()` is called like this: `encrypt(cipher, 1)`. What is `cipher`?

Comment: it's a variable, the dictionary

Comment: Wrap your `result +=` statement in a `try`/`except`. Also, you can do `for char in text` instead of using an index and you can just set all your text to either lower or upper instead of using the `if` and doing the case change mathematically (e.g. `text = text.upper()` as the first line of the function.

Comment: uh, sorry? i dont understand that, i'm very new to python

Comment: Please update your question with the code from around `line 105` in `main.py`. The error is in there.

Comment: Ignore the comment from Dennis. I need to see more code.

Comment: Yes, that's `line 105`. Please add more of the code, say 5 lines above and below.,

Comment: Oh, that's the request headers. I don't think that'll be useful

Comment: But when you say that, I hear: `"I think your efforts to help me are worthless"`. I can leave now, or I can wait for you to provide more code. Its up to you.

Comment: Nono I'm sorry if it sounded like that, I'm just doing "CipherValue": encrypt(cipher, 1) because I need to encrypt that dictionary and send a request to something.

Comment: Ok apology accepted. So why are you trying to encrypt a `tuple` (its not  dictionary) with a function which encrypts a string?

Comment: Oh my bad tuple, I need it to get encrypted so I can send a request to something with it, how would I encrypt the tuple? Also sorry for the late answer, had to do something @quamrana

Answer (score 0):

Your function `encrypt()` by its parameters seems to want to accept a `text` string as the first parameter and not a collection of strings.

The loop inside the function seems to be accessing individual characters of the string parameter given the name `char` and the use of `ord(char)`.

The reason for the error is that if a collection of strings is passed into `encrypt()` and one of them is an empty string, then `char` will be assigned that empty string and will thus produce the posted error: `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found`

A solution to the problem of the `cipher` variable being a `tuple` of strings is to iterate over it, passing each string to `encrypt()` and creating a new tuple from the results of each call.
For `line 105` in `main.py` you could have written this:

`"CipherValue": tuple(encrypt(item, 1) for item in cipher),`

Comment: This answer solves the reported error.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that the dictionary is given instead of the plaintext string. It also doesn't explain what the answer is, it just gives code. These kind of things should be in the answer to avoid this kind of confusion @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: So I shall edit the answer to include the relevant information contained in the comments to the question.